# How to get path to UITestActionLog.html from code

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Each test case saves results to a separate UITestActionLog.html file. But in the end of each test case I'd like to move that .html to a different folder and rename it.

Is it possible to do so in, say, [TestCleanup()]? If yes, then how can I programmatically get .html report location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TestContext` class contains several fields with "directory" in their names. These can be used to access the various directories associated with running the tests.

As well as managing the files as asked by your question the `TestContext` class has an `AddResultFile` method. The Microsoft documentation on this mehod is not clear, but it seems that the files are saved for failing tests and discarded for passing tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot! TestContext.TestResultsDirectory points to UITestActionLog.html folder

Answer (score -1):

To get the directory in which the UITestActionLog file will be located, use the `TestContext.TestResultsDirectory` Property. You can use below code to get the full path:

```
string fullPath = TestContext.TestResultsDirectory +"\" +"UITestActionLog.html";
```